# Showing that any linear operator can be written as a sum of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

Let $(V, \mathbb{C})$ be a complex - valued vector space. Let $A$ be any linear operator acting on this vector space. Suppose that $B = \{|v\rangle_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ is a basis set for $(V, \mathbb{C})$. Then, the linear operator $A$ may be written as $A = \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{kj}|v_{k}\rangle \langle v_{j}|$ - in terms of it's outer product.

I would appreciate **hints** in the direction of assisting me in writing $A = B + iC$ where $B,C$ are Hermitian and $i$ is an imaginary number.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is wrong: a sum of hermitian matrices is again hermitian.

Comment: Yes, they are close under matrix addition. Let me make clear the OP.

Comment: @kimchilover I don't see anything about linear combinations, I see "as a ***sum*** of Hermitian matrices".

Comment: @Mathematicing Please, state the problem clearly in the body of the post.

Answer (score 0):

One can write $A$ as the sum of a real symmetric matrix, a pure imaginary symmetric matric, a real antisymmetric matrix, and a pure imaginary antisymmetric matrix.  Each of these 4 kinds of pieces can be written in the form $B+iC$ for Hermetian $B$ and $C$, hence so can $A$.